# Unpacking result of delayed function

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed

While converting my program using delayed, I stumbled upon a commonly used programming pattern that doesn't work with delayed. Example:

```
from dask import delayed
@delayed
def myFunction():
    return 1,2

a, b = myFunction()
a.compute()
```

Raises: `TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable`
While the following work around does not. But looks a lot more clumsy

```
from dask import delayed
@delayed
def myFunction():
    return 1,2

dummy = myFunction()
a, b = dummy[0], dummy[1]
a.compute()
```

Is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `nout=` keyword as described in the [delayed docstring](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-api.html#dask.delayed.delayed)

```
@delayed(nout=2)
def f(...):
    return a, b

x, y = f(1)
```

#### Docstring

```
nout : int, optional
    The number of outputs returned from calling the resulting ``Delayed``
    object. If provided, the ``Delayed`` output of the call can be iterated
    into ``nout`` objects, allowing for unpacking of results. By default
    iteration over ``Delayed`` objects will error. Note, that ``nout=1``
    expects ``obj``, to return a tuple of length 1, and consequently for
    `nout=0``, ``obj`` should return an empty tuple.
```

Comment: Oh man this confused me for so long. This should be front-and-center on the docs.

Comment: Is there a way to set `nout` after the delayed object is already constructed?

Comment: I have a problem where the delayed object comes out of a reduction and a `to_delayed()` function. There doesn't seem to be a way to set `nout` for the `to_delayed()`. I know that it is a delayed tuple. It seems the only way is to explicitly construct delayed unpacking function like `(fst, snd) = dask.delayed(lambda t: t, nout=2)(delayedtuple)`.

Comment: You can always index your object directly.  `x, y = d[0], d[1]`

Comment: That one is way more succinct!