# unpacking a dask delayed object of list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, dask, dask-delayed

I have a function returning a tuple of two elements. The function is called with pool starmap to generate a list of tuples which are unpacked to two lists.

```
def func():
   #...some operations
   return (x,y)

def MP_a_func(func,iterable,proc,chunk):
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=proc)
    Result=pool.starmap(func,iterable,chunksize=chunk)
    pool.close()
    return Result
##
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results=MP_a_func(func,iterable,proc,chunk)

a,b=zip(*results)
```

I now wish to use dask `delayed` API as the following

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results=delayed(MP_a_func(func,iterable,proc,chunk))
```

is it possible to unpack tuples in the delayed object without using `results.compute()` ?

Thank your for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the number of outputs, the `delayed` function (or decorator) takes an optional `nout` arguments, and this will split the single delayed into that many delayed outputs. This sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen this used before, but it turns out it was around for quite a while: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602766/unpacking-result-of-delayed-function

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for another delayed function to unpack the tuple, in the example below, the delayed value of `return_tuple(1)` was not computed, but passed as a `delayed` object:

```py
import dask

@dask.delayed
def return_tuple(x):
    return x+1, x-1

@dask.delayed
def process_first_item(some_tuple):
    return some_tuple[0]+10

result = process_first_item(return_tuple(1))

dask.compute(result)
```

As per @mdurant's answer, it turns out `delayed` function/decorator has `nout` parameter, also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604704/10693596).