# Dask: How to return a tuple of futures in client.submit

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I need to return a tuple from a task which has to be unpacked in the main process because each element of the tuple will go to different dask tasks. I would like to avoid unnecessary communication so I think that the tuple elements should be Futures.

The best way I came up with is to scatter the data only to the same worker to get the future. Is there a better way to do it?

```py
import numpy as np
import time
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask.distributed import get_client, get_worker

def other_task(data):
    return len(data)

def costly_task():
    start = time.time()
    client = get_client()
    data = np.arange(100000000)
    metadata = len(data)
    print('worker time', time.time() - start)
    start = time.time()
    future_data, future_metadata = client.scatter(data, workers=[get_worker().id]), client.scatter(metadata, workers=[get_worker().id])
    print('scatter time', time.time() - start)
    return future_data, future_metadata

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client(processes=True)
    start = time.time()
    future_data, future_metadata = client.submit(costly_task).result()
    metadata = future_metadata.result()
    print('costly task time', time.time() - start)
    other_metadata = client.submit(other_task, future_data).result()
    print('total time', time.time() - start)
```

The times I get with the script above are:

```
worker time 0.12443423271179199
scatter time 0.7880995273590088
costly task time 0.923513650894165
total time 0.9366424083709717
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible via `delayed`:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import delayed

@delayed(nout=3)
def costly_task():
    return 1, 2, 3

client = Client(processes=True)

a, b, c = costly_task() # these are delayed
future_a, future_b, future_c = client.compute([a, b, c]) # split results
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604704/10693596) for further details.